# image repeat on gmail and hotmail only

Tags: images, repeat

I think the issue is in my css for background image. I checked the [google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/reference/supported_css) developer list and all in my css headerimage applies.

```
.headerImage {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat center;
}
```

Which is being used in my td tag

```
<td background="%%=v(@ColumnHeaderPic)=%% " class="container headerImage" height="313" width="600">
<!--[if gte mso 9]>           <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:275px;">             <v:fill type="frame" src="%%=v(@ColumnHeaderPic)=%%" />             <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">           <![endif]-->
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `no-repeat center` is not a valid value for the `background-repeat` property.

You should get the desired results by changing that line to:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Read here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I did change it as suggested with no change. However, I noticed when I put the style within the cell (<td background="%%=v(@ColumnHeaderPic)=%% " class="container headerImage" height="50%" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;" width="100%">) this kind of corrected the issue. I'm now dealing with white space under the image but at least it's not repeating the image. If you have any suggestions to get the white out that would be great. I tried adding display: block; with no luck though.

Comment: @RobertWynter As for dealing with the white space where the repeated image used to be, some options are (1) shrink that area to be the same size as the image (2) choose a larger image - maybe just crop the sides and make it bigger (3) add a darker background color instead of whitespace if you just need more contrast against the text.